# TCP/IP Socket Server ROS Node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I’ve multiple devices communicating via TCP/IP Socket. My intention is to integrate them into my ROS. Now I’m wondering whether it makes sense to have basis TCP/IP Socket Server node in ros, instead of integrating a TCP/IP Socket Connection in every ROS Node for my devices.

This service node should have services like sendByte sendASCII, etc. and publish topic for received data. I know that this is probably not fulfilling the High Level Conept of ROS but I thought it might make sense for my device nodes, since I wouldn’t have to integrate the tcp/socket every time.

Any Ideas on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11625/tcp/ip-socket-server-ros-node/) by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could make sense if you make it a nodelet instead of a node.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-24**:
It's probably the easiest to just propose it and look for some input/suggestions.

**Comment by [Mimax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1085/mimax/) on 2011-10-23**:
Thanks for that advice. Do you think it would make sense to propose this idea in the mailing lists to have such a nodelet as a common functionality in ros?